# turn multiple columns into rows corresponding to individual records

Tags: r

My challenge is that I want to turn this:

[image: original]

Into:

[image: desired]

Would anyone have any idea how to accomplish this? Would be much appreciated. Tried using `gather()` but don't really understand it's mechanism!

Comment: sorry, stack exchange does not allow me to embed images here yet

Comment: `rbind()` can help

Comment: Please post the data into the question so that we dont have to type it of of the image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: All of your comments are noted. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example that utilizes `gather()` from the `tidyr` package. For your next questions, please post the code used to create the data frame. In other words, help me help you!

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~person, ~s1, ~s2,
  "A", "Spec a", "Spec b",
  "B", "Spec c", "Spec d",
  "C", "Spec e", "Spec f"
)

df %>%
  gather(key = "Specialization_number", value = "Specialization", -person) %>%
  select(-Specialization_number) %>%
  arrange(person)
```

produces:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  person Specialization
   <chr>          <chr>
1      A         Spec a
2      A         Spec b
3      B         Spec c
4      B         Spec d
5      C         Spec e
6      C         Spec f
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Davis. Your comment about uploading code for the dataset is well-noted. I should have thought of that! In any case, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Either `tidyr::gather` or `reshape::melt` can transform your data from wide format to long format.

```
library(tidyr)
gather(data, Type, Specializations, -Person)

library(reshape)
melt(data, id.vars="Person")
```

Comment: Thank you R.S.! This is surprisingly elegant considering the code I was trying to write up. Got a lot to learn :)